# android studio terminal does not register environmental variables

Tags: windows, android-studio

If i write  echo in android studio terminal, it does not return path

```
PS D:\Programming\android\test> echo %PATH%
%PATH%
PS D:\Programming\android\test> echo $PATH
PS D:\Programming\android\test>
```

If I write echo %PATH% in cmd.exe terminal everything works fine